# Using angularfire $bind vs. $update for small tree of data

Tags: angularfire

I'm just starting my first project with AngularFire and am a little confused on using `$bind` for a whole tree of data vs. `$update` explicitly on each of the child elements.

Naively it would seem easy to `$bind` the root of the tree and be done. But the angular fire docs say:

> This sort of binding is most useful for primitive values like strings, booleans and numbers.

It makes sense to me that trying to sync a deep tree with 1,000s of nodes and many levels. But I'm looking at a case with more like 50 nodes and 3-4 levels. Am I missing something about `$bind` that would make it poorly suited to keeping the whole tree in sync automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you $bind against an entire tree, you are sending and receiving the entire tree for each change event. For example,

```
/widgets/one/color/
```

If I $bind() on widgets, each time any widget color changes, I now reconcile every widget in the system. Inversely, to update the color on a widget, I have to write the entire tree back to Firebase, effectively setting every single widget in the system to it's (hopefully) pre-existing value.

Instead, I can use a 2-way sync to pull in changes:

```
var ref = new Firebase(URL+'/widgets');
$scope.widgets = $firebase(ref);
```

And when I want to update one, do something like the following:

```
$scope.updateColor = function(widgetKey, color) {
    var child = $scope.widgets.$child(widgetKey);
    child.color = color;
    child.$save(); // only save one record, phew
});
```

Far more efficient and safer, since users won't be unintentionally overwriting changes in other records they didn't intend to modify.

If the list is only used by a single user and never modified concurrently, then this is less of an issue and the only concern becomes bandwidth (probably not a big deal for your 50 or so nodes being occasionally updated by a single person).

Comment: Thanks, this definitely help to clarify. (Docs pretty sketchy on this one)

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TAXmsQlSkYhY2isCKIAw?p=preview) for you which a simplest one CRUD example as you want.

You can also a [git](https://github.com/TUSHAR4541/Angulrjs-CRUD-with-bootstrap-modal) it.

Comment: Unless I'm missing it, this doesn't seem to use `$bind` at all, so not really what I was asking about.